# Having trouble with changing permalink setting in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

The default setting for permalink works fine with all of my pages but when i change it to other options like day and name, month and name ... it gives me 404 error.
This question might be asked by others in other ways but the answers did not help me.
Plus I m new in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially keep default permalink structure.
Kindly delete htaccess file in the root folder(if present). 
Finally select the required permalink structure.
Do clear the cache.

Comment: I deleted the htaccess file which was in my www folder, but whenever I change the permalink to something other than Default one, a new htaccess file will be created automatically in my www folder and the same error is appeared. I also cleared my web browser cache. Still dont know where is the problem?

Comment: In that case, set permalink to default, delete htaccess, and change the permalink again to desired type, as soon as new htaccess file is created change its permission to 444